# The Damerau-Levenshtein distance in C

Tags: c, dynamic-programming

I'm working on a spell checker and I need to optimize the Damerau-Levenshtein distance. For example... when 2 words have a distance greater than 3 (or a limit), I need to break the function. This will reduce the execution time. i was thinking veryfy when the min is greater than 3, but through the proccess, sometimes the min is greater, because Damerau-Levenshtein distance works on a table of min values. I think to add a condition like i == j, but when a word is longer than the other  it fail. The code is version from Internet.

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include "levenshtein.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int min_(int a, int b){
    return (a<b)?a:b;
}



int dist_dlevenshtein(char* p_string1, char* p_string2, int umbral)
{
    int l_string_length1 = strlen(p_string1);
    int l_string_length2 = strlen(p_string2);
    int d[l_string_length1+1][l_string_length2+1];

    int i;
    int j;
    int l_cost;

    for (i = 0;i <= l_string_length1;i++)
    {
        d[i][0] = i;
    }
    for(j = 0; j<= l_string_length2; j++)
    {
        d[0][j] = j;
    }
    for (i = 1;i <= l_string_length1;i++)
    {
        for(j = 1; j<= l_string_length2; j++)
        {
            if( p_string1[i-1] == p_string2[j-1] )
            {
                l_cost = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                l_cost = 1;
            }
            d[i][j] = min_(
            d[i-1][j] + 1,                  // delete
            min_(d[i][j-1] + 1,         // insert
            d[i-1][j-1] + l_cost)           // substitution
            );
            if( (i > 1) && 
            (j > 1) && 
            (p_string1[i-1] == p_string2[j-2]) && 
            (p_string1[i-2] == p_string2[j-1])
            ) 
            {
            d[i][j] = min_(d[i][j],d[i-2][j-2] + l_cost); // transposition
            }
        }
    }
    return d[l_string_length1][l_string_length2];
}```
````

Comment: With a loop like `for (i = 0;i <= l_string_length1;i++)` you will include the string null-terminator in your calculations. Use `<` as condition to not do that.

Comment: Also, please don't just blindly copy code you find "on the Internet". That leads to [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) which is a bad thing. If you really want to learn something, try to implement it yourself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  yes you are right, the original code is to c++, and i  tested on a board step to step to learn how works. Thanks for your answer!